# Selecting additional values after annotate in Django

Tags: django

I have a model, IndividualResult, for an athlete's performance during a competition.

To select the fastest time for each athlete I used:

```
qs.values('athlete').annotate(pb=Min('time'))
```

This returns only the athlete_id and its fastest time.

How can I access the other fields in my IndividualResult model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access additional fields in `IndividualResult` model since the resulting annotated queryset is of grouped items. That is the individual results of an athlete have been grouped to come up with the fastest time `Min('time')`. Extra fields will have to be annotated to have access to them.

Comment: I used `.values('athlete')` ot group the result by athlete.
Adding more fields to the values groups the result by more values.

Comment: In a complete other model actually, registered as a foreign key in the IndividualResult model